# Como verificar pela url se a página é a index

Tags: javascript, html, url, indexof

Como eu consigo através do JS, se a minha url é a index?

Eu tenho um código assim:

```
window.onload = function () {
    url = window.location.href;

    if (url.match("/dashboard")) {
        [...]
    }
}
```

que verifica se ele está na url do dashboard. Mas como é que eu faço para verificar se está na index? Já que nela nao há um `/index` na url, é simplesmente `https://localhost:8080`?

Não posso fazer assim:

```
if (url == "https://localhost:8080/") {
    [...]
}
```

Pois futuramente esta url certamente será outra, e precisarei mudar o código (oque eu não quero).

Comment: Qual é o valor de `url` quando você acessa a index?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss o valor é `https://localhost:8080/`

Answer (score 3):

Ao invés de `href`, você pode utilizar `pathname`, que é a parte da URL que você quer verificar:

```js
const url = window.location;

console.log(url.pathname);
```

Nesse caso, na index o valor de `url.pathname` será `"/"`.

Comment: e no caso de um caminho ?? Por exemplo, se a url for `https://localhost:8080/dash/board/1/js`? o valor será `/js`?

Comment: @edro Não, será o valor respectivo ao *path* da URL. Veja mais em [O que é um URL?](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Learn/Questoes_comuns/O_que_e_um_URL)